# BST: Name of the ordering property

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Assume you have an array of

```
[10, 2, 3, 11, 4]
```

and

```
[4, 2, 11, 10, 3]
```

If constructing BSTs from the following arrays, 
then both constructed BSTs are different even though the data is the same. If both lists are sorted prior to making the BSTs then you would get the same BST, is there a specific algorithm which allows you to sort two or more BSTs so given the same data, they always give the same layout?

Is there a term for this property?

Comment: in the line 'is there a specific algorithm which allows you to sort two or more BSTs so given the ....'  what do you mean by sort the BST ?

Comment: sort two trees with the same elements so that they have the nodes both in the same positions

Comment: I've never seen a term used for this concept before. It comes up quite a lot, but it's often described as "two BSTs with the same elements."